# Missing expression error with ORACLE query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select extract (year from CRIME_DATE) year,
SUM (CRIME_NO)
from crime
group by select extract (year from CRIME_DATE) CRIME_DATE
order by select extract (year from CRIME_DATE) year
```

I am trying to use the above query to produce a chart in application builder in apex but to make sure it works i am testing it on SQL commands but i keep getting the missing expression error can anyone help?

Comment: you should remove CRIME_DATE and year from the end of the group by and order by lines

Comment: no i still get the same error

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: you have the SELECT keyword in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY. Please remove them as well as the column aliases.

Comment: also remove the select from before the extract

Comment: Ok i've tried what jospeh suggested but i get the not single group by function error, i'll try the other suggestions

Comment: can you post a sample of the data you get with the fixed query if you replace Sum (CRIME_NO) with just CRIME_NO and remove the group by function?

Comment: I dont get any data just the following error  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Actally i didnt remove the sum, i've done that and it just gives the years and the crime number, im not sure how to post it as it just appears as a big paragraph when i try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select extract (year from CRIME_DATE) year,
SUM (CRIME_NO)
from crime
group by extract (year from CRIME_DATE)
order by extract (year from CRIME_DATE)
```

This should fix the problems.  You had additional column names after the extract in group by/order by (if you want multiple columns to identify these by you should use commas)  and they also had selects in the line which should have been there.

For the chart error....maybe try this (little rusty on Oracle so not sure this will work):

```
select extract (year from CRIME_DATE) year,
SUM (CRIME_NO)
from crime
group by extract (year from CRIME_DATE)
order by year
```

Comment: This works in SQL commands but when i apply it to the chart i get this error: 1 error has occurred

    Invalid chart query: select extract (year from CRIME_DATE), SUM (CRIME_NO) from crime group by extract (year from CRIME_DATE) order by extract (year from CRIME_DATE)

    Use the following syntax:

    SELECT LINK, LABEL, VALUE
    FROM   ...

    Or use the following syntax for a query returning multiple series:

    SELECT LINK, LABEL, VALUE1 [, VALUE2 [, VALUE3...]]
    FROM   ...

    LINK URL
    LABEL Text that displays along a chart axis.
    VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3...

Comment: @user3499533 try the updated answer...not sure if this is "legal" or not in Oracle

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - no, that isn't legal; you can only refer to a column alias in an `order by`, not in the `group by`.

Comment: @AlexPoole so the modified version I just updated would be legal then

Comment: @user3499533 sorry, I'm out of ideas for the chart error

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - yes, that updated version is fine. (Saves a little bit of maintenance compared to your first query I suppose!). The chart error is because of the aliases APEX requires.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing just the chart error - Marshall Tigerus has addressed your initial error - the error from the chart builder is quite clear, and there are samples. You need to use specific column aliases; and you also need to `COUNT` rather than `SUM`, I think:

```
select NULL link,
  extract (year from CRIME_DATE) label,
  COUNT (CRIME_NO) value
from crime
group by extract (year from CRIME_DATE)
order by extract (year from CRIME_DATE);
```

Comment: The query works but the results seem to be inaccurate for example i have 3 crimes which have a crime_date with a year of 2013 but for some reason its shows as a staggering 21 crime when i only have 10 crimes in the table, any ideas why?

Comment: @user3499533 - you're doing SUM; did you mean COUNT, perhaps? Summing the crime numbers would seem quite an odd thing to do - it doesn't tell you anything really. And you could get big numbers, quite quickly...